# Importing existing JSP project to Eclipse or Net Beans

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

I am trying to import project from some server on my localhost.

I would prefer to import it in NetBeans, but Eclipse is also fine. I set up Tomcat server in NetBeans for now. Then I tried to create new Java Web project with existing source and then I go through the wizard, and when I should select Web pages folder, Web-inf content it says: "Web Pages folder overlaps Project folder."

But I am not sure what kind of setup should I have there.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly import it through eclipse , there is a option of importing some project  , don't create a new project

Comment: there is an option for importing projects, but only if projects have Eclipse project file (which I dont have)